# Put the text right-aligned

Tags: javascript

I'm working with codepen.io and I am creating a bargraph.
The graph has scales: One on the left and one on the right side.

The problem is that I want the text of value on the left side to be right-aligned. I can't use CSS to do this, and I believe javascript would do the job.

Here are the two functions I am using to draw the scales and the link to my project goes bellow.

```
function drawScalesLeft(numOfScales)
{
    console.log("Zeichne linke Skala mit " + numOfScales + " Einheiten");
    for(i=0; i <= numOfScales ; i++)
    {
        var currentHeight = document.getElementById('bargraph').height;
        var yPos = 279.75 * i / numOfScales + 10;
        var marker = document.createElementNS(svgNS,"rect");
            marker.setAttributeNS(null, 'x', 115);
            marker.setAttributeNS(null, 'y', yPos);
            marker.setAttributeNS(null, 'height', 0.2);
            marker.setAttributeNS(null, 'width', 10);
        document.getElementById("bargraph").appendChild(marker);
        var markerText = document.createElementNS(svgNS,"text");
            markerText.setAttributeNS(null, 'x', 50); //Textposition (horinzontal)
            markerText.setAttributeNS(null, 'y', yPos+5);

            markerText.textContent = (100-100 *i/ numOfScales).toFixed(digits) + " %";
        document.getElementById("bargraph").appendChild(markerText); 
   }
}

function drawScalesRight(numOfScales)
{
    console.log("Zeichne rechte Skala mit " + numOfScales + " Einheiten");

    for(i=0; i <= numOfScales; i++)
    {
        var currentHeight = document.getElementById('bargraph').height;
        var yPos = 279.75 * i / numOfScales + 10;
        var marker = document.createElementNS(svgNS,"rect");
            marker.setAttributeNS(null, 'x', 175);
            marker.setAttributeNS(null, 'y', yPos);
            marker.setAttributeNS(null, 'height', 0.2);
            marker.setAttributeNS(null, 'width', 10);
        document.getElementById("bargraph").appendChild(marker);
        var markerText = document.createElementNS(svgNS,"text");
            markerText.setAttributeNS(null, 'x', 195);//Textposition (horinzontal)
            markerText.setAttributeNS(null, 'y', yPos+5);
            markerText.textContent = (500-500 * i/ numOfScales).toFixed(digits2) + " m";
        document.getElementById("bargraph").appendChild(markerText);
    }
}
```

Full code:

[codepen.io/Cleanwater/pen/LWQyJm?editors=0010](http://codepen.io/Cleanwater/pen/LWQyJm?editors=0010)

Comment: you should reduce your code to a minimum: [mcve]  
For other SO-users it would be easier if you just use english comments.

Comment: @hering , do you know, putting `[mcve]` will bring the title automatically like this ->  [mcve]

Comment: now I do :) Thanks for that...

Comment: thank you for the correction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to properly calculate the `x` value for the `text` nodes.

After line `55` that looks like this

```
document.getElementById("bargraph").appendChild(markerText);
```

add this

```
markerText.setAttributeNS(null, 'x', 100 - markerText.getBBox().width);
```

And all should be good.

Also, remove line `50`

```
markerText.setAttributeNS(null, 'x', 50); //Textposition (horinzontal)
```

Comment: Is there a way to make the text in the center? In line 101 in the code

Comment: On line `105` add `text.setAttributeNS(null, 'x', document.getElementById('bargraph').clientWidth / 2 - text.getBBox().width / 2);`, then delete `101`.

Comment: Thank you, for your help :)